Where is the documentation for and how to include dependencies inside .jar
Nothing complex. Simple straight forward project.
I just followed very first guide to create Maven project.
As mentioned there, when I ran
java -cp target/log2json2db-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.company.com.log2json2db.App

It properly printed "Hello World".
Later, I go on adding some of the dependencies like, hibernate, mysql, log4j etc under "dependencies" section.
And added
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

Then I ran "mvn clean package" to create ".jar" file.
Jar was created but it does not include libraries like slf4j.
Now when I again tried to run using "java -cp..."
I'm getting below error message.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at org.company.com.log2json2db.App.<clinit>(App.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

What I mainly need help with is, I tried searching in the documentation to find whether I need to change the scope OR whether I need to add some other dependencies etc. I searched under "dependency management" section of the documentation. But cannot find out what I have to change to include dependency libraries.
Can anyone please provide me the documentation link and possibly an answer on how can I include dependencies inside ".jar"?
Below is the pom.xml for your reference.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tutorials</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
        <version>6.6.4.Final</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.company.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>log2json2db</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>log2json2db</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>22</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.11.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Optionally: parameterized tests support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven
            defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see
                https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see
                https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.13.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see
                https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>

UPDATE
Added Apache Maven Shade plugin.
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

Apart from using Apache Maven Shade as suggested in the comments, I had to disable pluginManagement tag for Maven Shade to take effect.

It seems like you are trying to build a fat jar (i.e. a jar with your code, as well as all dependencies). If this is the case, please read: Building a fat jar using maven.

"Where is the documentation for and how to include dependencies inside .jar" -> JAR File Specification

You can use the Maven Assembly Plugin by adding it to your pom.xml file in the <build> part. After that rerun the command mvn clean package, this should work.

It is found that, Maven Shade plugin is recommended over Maven Assembly plugin.

Dependencies inside a .jar file
I know you asked specifically for this:

Can anyone please provide me the documentation link and possibly an answer on how can I include dependencies inside ".jar"?

And while you can do this, see the answer from Uros, you have a few drawbacks:

jar file signing will fail to work
you might encounter issues as the dependencies may need to be unpacked
This is not a "keep it simple" approach.

Actual goal of your question
Clearly you want to create a distribution? Let me show yo ua few more options.
Default layout with script
Instead, please consider the approach taken in the JReleaser plugin, which can create a template-based script (script.cmd for Windows and just 'script' for unix/linux systems):
https://jreleaser.org/guide/latest/reference/assemble/java-archive.html
Using the dependency plugin, you just assemble all dependencies into a lib folder and then run the jreleaser goal. You will have such a directory layout:
myapp-1.0.0
|- bin
|  |- myapp.cmd
|  `- myapp(.sh)
`- lib
   |- logback.jar
   `- slf4j.jar

(just a simple example).
Additionally, this plugin creates a .zip or .tar.gz file which can be attached to your project as an artifact.
